# Django bulk create, ignore failed foreign keys?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Is there a way to ignore foreign key errors when doing a `Model.objects.bulk_create` and postgres? I'm aware of the `ignore_conflicts=True` flag and this seems to fix some errors, but I'm specifically dealing with data where the ForeignKey is not guaranteed to exist for one reason or another (such as the data being incomplete, deleted or more).

I'm aware that this can be done at the database level using `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` but I just want this for a particular `bulk_create` call. What can I do here?